# How to set select options value to php variable without using form POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have an select options that selects a customer with some corresponding values to that customer, the values are retrieved using JavaScript function and document.getElementById(“ ”) with the select id, Displaying using the id of the document.getElementById(“ ”)  in an input .
For an query I need to set one value of the customer to an PHP variable to be used specifically the customer id.
I did try using FORM POST but is not what I need as I am already using an FORM to sent values to another page that is not relevant.

I only want the customer id in PHP variable to use in my query.

Where i select the customer:

```
<form action="../Database/insert_quote.php" method="post"> 
           <input name="c_id" id="id" />                               <!---**** Customer ID  ****--->
              <div class="cardIn">
                 <label>Customer</label>
                 <div class="select margin-top" style="width: 450px;">
                    <select name="customer" id="customer_email" >
                       <option value="text" name="customer"  disabled selected>Click to See Customers</option>
                        
                          <?php
                          
                          $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM addclient");   //***  Select customer ***
                            while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
                             {
                           echo '<option 
                             value="'.$data['company'].'"
                             data-email="'. $data['email'].'" 
                             data-id="'. $data['id'].'" 
                             data-percent_discount="'. $data['percent_discount'].'" 
                             data-value_discount="'. $data['value_discount'].'" 
                             >'. $data['company'] . '
                             </option>';
                            }
                          ?>
                         </select>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </form
```

How i retrieve the customer values using JavaScript in id:

```
 <script>
     var mySelect = document.getElementById("customer_email");
      
       mySelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
           
       var myOption = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-email");
       document.getElementById('email').value = myOption;
           
        var myOptionTwo = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id");
        document.getElementById('id').value = myOptionTwo;
           
        var myOptionTwo = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-percent_discount");
        document.getElementById('percent_discount').value = myOptionTwo;
           
        var myOptionTwo = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-value_discount");
        document.getElementById('value_discount').value = myOptionTwo;
                 
        });
       
  </script>
```

The query where i want to use the customer id as an PHP variable:

```
<select name="item" id="item">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option>
                               
       <?php  //  $Customerid = 'The customer id selected at the customer select';
       // $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customer_product WHERE customer LIKE '$Customerid' ");
        $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customer_product ");
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
                                  
        echo '<option value="'.$data['product'].'"  
        data-new_price_rate="' . $data['new_price_rate'].'" 
        data-description="' . $data['description'] . '"  >' 
        . $data['product']. '</option>';
         }
         ?>
         </select>
```

Comment: If you don't want to post back then you should consider using AJAX

Comment: with each customer selected there are multiple value not only the customer name, will AJAX fetch the specific value in the customer selected?

Comment: AJAX is just a way of sending a HTTP request asynchronously from a browser, without refreshing the page or posting back. You can send and receive whatever you want via it - that's up to you and how you write your code.